# Update cursor command for ArcGIS updating coordinates, but coordinate location is not updating?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I am writing a script to allow the user to input coordinates to update the location of a point.

```
 rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("C:\Users\Hannah\Desktop\Marcellus Shale data\GDB and Maps\Marcellus.gdb\Marcellus_Wells\Update_Cursor")
for row in rows:
    row.Latitude = float(raw_input('Latitude: '))
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row
del rows

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("C:\Users\Hannah\Desktop\Marcellus Shale data\GDB and Maps\Marcellus.gdb\Marcellus_Wells\Update_Cursor")
for row in rows:
    row.Longitude = float(raw_input('Longitude: '))
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row
del rows


inFeatures = ["C:\Users\Hannah\Desktop\Marcellus Shale data\GDB and Maps\Marcellus.gdb\Marcellus_Wells\Update_Cursor"]
outLocation = "C:\Users\Hannah\Desktop\Marcellus Shale data\GDB and Maps\Database Script\Shapefiles"
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

The script "works"; that is, the shapefile I created at the end contains the new coordinates in the place of the old coordinates. However, when I drag the new shapefile into the ArcMap screen, the point goes to the location of the old coordinates, even though the attribute table is displaying the new coordinates.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're updating the fields Latitude and Longitude, but not the actual geometry. To update the record's geometry, you need to create a new point object and store it in the shape field.

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("C:\Users\Hannah\Desktop\Marcellus Shale data\GDB and Maps\Marcellus.gdb\Marcellus_Wells\Update_Cursor")
for row in rows:
    point = new arcpy.point()
    latitude = float(raw_input('Latitude: '))
    longitude = float(raw_input('Longitude: '))
    row.Latitude = latitude
    row.Longitude = longitude
    point.Y = latitude
    point.X = longitude        
    pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
    row.setValue('SHAPE', pointGeometry)
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row
del rows
```

That should get you pretty close. If possible, you should use the [data access cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/). They are much faster and easier to work with.